# Powershell related questions

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell, powershell-3.0

Here is my situation:

1) I already use "RunspaceConfiguration" -- C# code -- to call a powershell script;

2) What's inside the script is also straightforward -- use regsvr32 to register COM dll

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & 'regsvr32.exe' $registerdllfullpath }
```

3) Without C# code, in order to call regsvr32, we have to right-click and choose "Run As Administrator" to launch powershell.

So how could I do this?

---

Someone recommend use something like:

```
$user = Get-Credential 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -Credential $user -ScriptBlock { & 'regsvr32.exe' $registerdllfullpath }
```

But:

1) -Credential cannot be used without -ComputerName. But if it's just local machine, we still need to turn on Windows-Remote-Management service, which is a little bit clumsy;

2) Since I am already the local admin to trigger the powershell, it asks for my username and pasword again, which seems redundant?

3) Last but not least, it's not working... :-(

Thanks a lot!

**------------------------Edit --------------------**

I googled 1 solution which is like this in my PS script: [It does the job]

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & ","'regsvr32.exe'", "$registerdllfullpath } "
```

The original script now becomes the **ArgumentList**, which I am not sure whether is the correct way or not :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `runas` to UAC elevate locally *is* the correct way.

But, remember UAC only applies locally. If you have a non-elevated admin account, that is also an admin on the remote machine, the directly remoted script will run with elevation remotely (without the use of `runas` or similar).

The assumption is that you enable remote management (with Windows RMS) when you want to remotely manage.